# Clojure-New Cond Macro?

Tags: clojure

I don't understand this code from the [clojure 1.5 release notes](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#24-new-threading-macros). It uses the `cond->` macro. For example, how would it translate into pre-1.5 code?

```
user=> (cond-> 1
               true inc
               false (* 42)
               (= 2 2) (* 3))
6
```

Comment: where did you find that?

Comment: At a guess I would imagine this gives 6 = `(* 3 (inc 1))`, where it threads the first argument through any functions whose predicate evaluates to true.

Comment: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md#24-new-threading-macros

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Each step changes the result if the test is true, or leaves it alone if the test is false.

You could write this in 1.4 by threading anonymous functions:

```
user> (-> 1 (#(if true (inc %) %)) 
            (#(if false (* % 42) %)) 
            (#(if (= 2 2) (* % 3) %)))
6
```

Though the `cond->` does not introduce new functions, instead it generates a binding form to be more efficient:

```
user> (let [g 1 
            g (if true (inc g) g) 
            g (if false (* g 42) g) 
            g (if (= 2 2) (* g 3) g)] 
      g)
6
```

and uses a `gensym` for `g` incase some of the forms use the symbol `g`

---

`cond->>` is very similar, it just places the threaded symbol in a diferent place.

```
user> (let [g 1 
            g (if true (inc g) g) 
            g (if false (* 42 g) g) 
            g (if (= 2 2) (* 3 g) g)] 
       g)
6
```

which in this example gives the same result because `*` and `+` are commutative.

Comment: I like the middle example very... very much. That made it a lot more clear.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that the `cond->>` macro does a similiar routine?

Comment: sorry, I was editing it while you commented, which was the middle?